# Set 'environmentVariables' for different sites in IIS automatically in azure pipeline

Tags: powershell, asp.net-core, iis, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have release with pipeline that have couple '[IIS web app deploy](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/IISWebAppDeploymentOnMachineGroupV0/README.md)' jobs that deploys one  ASP.NET Core web API application in two sites in IIS in my agent (it needs for 2 different regions).

After this I need to setup different environmentVariables for each site. I used to do this manually (something like [this](https://ifyoudo.net/how-to-setup-aspnetcore_environment-variable-on-an-iis-website)). Now I'm trying to do it automatically. I wrote PS script that works fine in my agent machine:

```
Add-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/MY_SITE_NAME'  -filter "system.webServer/aspNetCore/environmentVariables" -name "." -value @{name='ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT';value='my_value'}
```

I'm trying to run this script as '[PowerShell v2 task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/powershell-v2?view=azure-pipelines&viewFallbackFrom=azure-devops)' after IIS deployment but it has no effect:
[image: tasks in pipeline]

Any ideas how to set different 'environmentVariables' for different sites in IIS automatically?

Comment: Did you run your script via administrator privileges? Have you tried to run your script with task [powershell on target machines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/powershell-on-target-machines-v3?view=azure-pipelines) via administrator privileges?

Comment: When I run it on the agent in PS I run it 'as administrator'.
I just tried 'PowerShellOnTargetMachines@3' with setting ip address of machine and username/password of admin. Same result...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to work correctly. I was experimenting on an old release, and all just I had to do was **create a new one**.

Comment: You could mark it as an answer for other users who have the same issue with yours as reference